# Symfony: set "public" property in "services.yaml" for all classes in selected directory

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to have an ability to create services by theirs class-names.
One of the way to do it: is setting "public" property in "services.yaml"
BUT I DON'T WANT to set "public" property for ALL classes in my project

services.yaml

```
services:
  _defaults:
    public: false      # it helps to optimize performance, doesn't it?

App\Service\Service1
  public: true

App\Service\Service2
  public: true

App\Service\Service3
  public: true

  App\Service\*       # why I can't use something like "*" here ???
    public: true
```

Service1.php

```
namespace App\Service;
class Service1 
{
  // important: every service can have one or more dependencies (Foo, Bar, Baz ... etc)
  public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar)
  {
    $this->foo = $foo;
    //..........
  }
}
```

MyController.php

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) 
{
  $this->container = $container;
}

// hier $className is any class name like "App/Service/xxxx"
public function myAction (string $className) 
{
  return $this->container->get($className);
}
```

**Questions:**

- is there a way to set "public" property for directory?
- is there a better way to create an instance of service by class-name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can utilize YAML import features to generalize the configuration that you need, making it easier to maintain.

For example:

```yaml
# /config/services.yaml
imports:
    - { resource: 'services/public/*.yaml' } # Import public services
    - { resource: 'services/private/*.yaml' } # Import private services
```

Though, as mentioned, forcing container services to be public goes against Symfony conventions, and will not be supported in future versions. Use dependency injection instead of interacting with the service container directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible. I tested it with Symfony 5.3.

See the last part in this services.yaml:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    App\Messenger\Handler\Event\:
        resource: '../src/Messenger/Handler/Event/'
        public: true
```

Similar to controllers you can include multiple classes via `resource` and make them public. But please be aware of the other answers/comments. Usually you should use dependency injection to load the services you need.

Alternatively (or even better) you could set a tag and use an iterable via dependency injection. See https://symfony.com/doc/5.3/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you need to set services to public? It goes against Symfony best practices which discourage fetching services from the container directly.

If you wish to define services named by their class name, it is enough to reference them with:

```
services:
    App\Service\Service1: ~
    App\Service\Service2: ~
    App\Service\Service3: ~

    App\Service\Service4:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Service\Service1'
            - '@App\Service\Service2'
            - '@App\Service\Service3'
```

and then inject them to your controllers directly, instead of using the container.

Comment: Thanks Edi. Could you please write why can I "inject them to my controllers directly" ?

Comment: My problem: I don't want to change services.yaml every time I add a new service

Comment: @AlexLysenko You can use autowiring for your services to avoid defining your services manually: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html